# preg_replace removing all apart from last matching elements

Tags: php, preg-replace

working on an inherited WordPress theme and the client has reported an issue with some links.

If the user has added 3 (example) links:

```
<p><a href="#">Where to Invest</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Where to Invest 2</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Where to Invest 3</a></p>
```

Only the last one is shown on the page, looking through the code I can see that the content is parsed through a function that adds classes to anchor links:

```
function style_content_call_to_action($content, $size='large'){
    $content = preg_replace('/<p><a.*href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/p>/si', '<p><a href="$1" class="object button '.$size.'">$2</a></p>', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Is there a way I can adjust this so that it works with all buttons? And doesn't remove all but the last?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your regex pattern to make it accurate and not grab everything on end with `(.*)`:

```
'/<p><a.*href="([^">]*)">([^<>]*)<\/a><\/p>/i'
```